# export pdf using plotly python

Tags: python, pdf, export, plotly

I generate a plotly graph using this:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plot_url = py.plot(fig, filename='stacked-bar')
```

I tried generating a pdf using:

```
from xhtml2pdf import pisa

result_file = open('report.pdf', "w+b")

pisa_status = pisa.CreatePDF(
url,                 
dest=result_file)            

result_file.close()
```

But I end up getting a pdf file with the url on it instead of the graph.

How can I export the plotly graph into a pdf? One the webpage, when I click the export button I am able to generate a jpeg and png but not a pdf. Also, I'm unable to control the size of the graph when exporting the, how can I control the size? Stretch out the graph making it a little wider.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The APIs have now changed, so I thought I'd post an update..

The new way of doing it is to use [plotly.io.write_image](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.io.write_image.html)

**Here is an example:**

```
plotly.io.write_image(fig, 'output_file.pdf', format='pdf')
```

The following formats are supported: png, jpg (or jpeg), webp, svg, pdf

Comment: Is it possible to save multiple figs as each separate page?

Comment: Just to add onto this, the current [docs](https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/), you can just take the `fig` object to export the image using the command `fig.write_image(your_fig_name.your_extension)`

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation for offline usage https://plot.ly/python/offline/ you can export images with:

```
plotly.plotly.image.save_as(figure, 'my_plot.png')
```

But to export pdf you have to have a paid account. Using free account you can export only png or jpg formats (100 API calls a day). But **not pdf**s.

In case if you stack with the error like:

> exceptions.PlotlyError(return_data['error'])

than there is a chance that you have some authentication problems to access Plotly API. Make sure you have an account and configure you ~/.plotly/.credentials with correct user name and api_key (you can find it in profile settings).

To control the size of the graph you need to [setup your layout](https://plot.ly/python/setting-graph-size/) accordingly.